# How to force HTTP URLs to be rewritten to HTTPS when using curl command line

Tags: linux, http, https, curl

I'm using some public build scripts that call dependencies from URLs beginning with http://. These build scripts fail as the company firewall blocks the download of files over http and require downloads to be over https.

Modifying the build scripts is not ideal. Is there a way, system wide, to force curl to use https when given http URLs?

If not, could a wrapper script for curl be used to upgrade http to https, and if so, how?

Comment: Use a text editor or sed on the script to replace `http://`.

Comment: @harrymc yes, I have had to do this but next time the scripts update the changes get lost. I'm looking for a solution to system-wide upgrade http to https without having to modify anywhere that is using http. Think of it like the browser extension https everywhere but for curl.

Answer (score 0):

Is this build script calling the `curl` command directly? If so, I don't know how you would adjust the output `curl` without directly changing the build scripts. I know you said it wasn't ideal, but wouldn't it be pretty easy to just open them in something like `vscode`, and just find and replace all instances of 'http://' with 'https://'?

Beyond that, you would maybe be able to go into the config files of `curl`, but I'm not aware if you'd be able to get your desired result through that method or not.

Another option that would technically work, though your network admin might not like it, is to just hook up a VPN while you run the command, so all the traffic exits through secure UDP channels, and your VPN forwards all the traffic through http on their own end. Depending the strength of the firewall, this might not be an option either, but I figured I'd mention it.

Comment: Yes, the scripts call curl directly and for now I have edited the scripts but I'm looking for a solution system-wide ideally. Either through some global config of curl or by wrapping curl command with my own to replace any http URLs with https.

Thank you for your suggestion of using VPN but that is out of the question in my case as the corporate network is severely locked down for regulatory reasons.

Comment: maybe it could be possible to create a basic python find and replace wrapper? So essentially if it calls `curl [parameters]` you just go through and explicitly replace all instances of 'http://' with 'https://', then call the real `curl` function with the updated parameters? Same could probably be achieved easily with bash instead of python. I'd recommend also adding in behavior for if the site doesn't have an associated https server (it's running http1.0 for example).